# How are charges distributed on a capacitor in the following circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

Four metallic plates are used to form two identical capacitors as shown in the figure.

[image]

Initially the plates were uncharged. Two batteries of different emf are connected as shown.
We have to find the charge on each capacitor after steady state is achieved.
So first I took charges on lower plates of  X and Y to be $q$ and $q'$.Then applied Kirchhoff's law.
$$5-\frac qC-2+\frac{q'}{C}=0$$
where C is the capacitance of the given capacitors.
Now I have no idea how to proceed further.
I thought a lot about it, but still I am having difficulty in analyzing how charges are given out and distributed by each battery. *(Ignore the dots present in each capacitor)*.
Given answer is $q=-q'=\frac{3C}{2}$

Comment: If capacitors in series have same C the charges q and q' should be identical and with same orientation....

Comment: @Krešimir Bradvica ,If that is the case then the kirchhoffs equation doesn't make sense as it becomes 3=0

Comment: I just said that capacitor terms in the equation should have same sign.....

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mr. Bradvica that the charges should be equal, but the left side capacitor is positive on the bottom, and the other is positive on top. The 3 volt potential difference is divided between them.

Comment: Can you please explain why and how.As I am unable to proceed with equations